# Does looksrare scan rinkeby - testnet?

Tags: nft, erc-721, testnets, rinkeby, markets

It is known that NFT collections located on the rinkeby testnet appear automatically on testnets.opensea.io.
Do NFT collections located on the rinkeby network also appear in lookshare.org?
If not, how does one test other marketplaces for rinkeby NFT collections?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes they do have Rinkeby url: https://rinkeby.looksrare.org/

Hope this is helpful.